# How to add multiple while loop in signle one

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a multiple while loop in my php file. First while loop data is loaded and then second while loop data is loaded and then third.

But i want to show data time wise for example recent data post is come first.

here is my php code example:

//data load for status

```
<?php  
   $status_res=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT datetime,status FROM status");    
   while($status=mysqli_fetch_array($status_res))
   {
     echo "load status";
      echo "<br>".$status['datetime'];
      echo "</br>". $status['status'];
   }
?>
```

//now while loop  for load change profile picture

```
<?php
 $profile=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT datetime,src FROM profile_photo");
 while($profile_r=mysqli_fetch_array($profile))
 {
     echo "load profile pic";
     echo "<br>".profile_r['datetime'];
     echo "<br>".$profile_r['src'];         
 }
?>
```

//now load other data

```
<?php
  $other_data=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT fname,datetime FROM other_tbl")
  while($other=mysqli_fetch_array($other_data))
  {
      echo "<br> other data";
      echo "<br>".$other['datetime];
      echo "<br>".$other['fname'];
  }
?>
```

then now using this code i getting following output bt there is bugs of displaying data

```
load status
2017-07-22 16:22:12
this is my first status    
2017-07-22 16:20:12
this is my second status
load profile
2017-07-22 16:25:12
this is my first profile    
2017-07-22 16:24:12
this is my second profile    
load status
2017-07-22 16:30:12
vishal
2017-07-22 16:28:12
vishal
```

But i want to out put like this.

```
load status
2017-07-22 16:30:12
vishal
2017-07-22 16:28:12
vishal
load profile
2017-07-22 16:25:12
this is my first profile    
2017-07-22 16:24:12
this is my second profile  
load status
2017-07-22 16:22:12
this is my first status     
2017-07-22 16:20:12
this is my second status
```

so how to solve that problems??
thank you

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. The output described doesn't match the code provided. And the difference between what you have and what you want is just the order of the 3 loops. ?

Comment: sorry, but really i don't understand your problem !

Comment: you need to combine all there tables based on some primary key and foreign key concept and then fetch data using join

Comment: Provide table structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you have to put all data in one table and sort them with the datetime

```
<?php  
    $array = array();

    $status_res=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT datetime,status FROM status";    
    while($status=mysqli_fetch_array($status_res))
    {
        $array[] = array(
            'title' => 'status',
            'value' => $status['status'],
            'datetime' => $status['datetime'],
            'output' => "<br>{$status['datetime']}<br>{$status['status']}"
        );
    }

    $profile=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT datetime,src FROM profile_photo";
    while($profile_r=mysqli_fetch_array($profile))
    {

        $array[] = array(
            'title' => 'profile',
            'value' => $profile_r['src'],
            'datetime' => $profile_r['datetime'],
            'output' => "<br>{$profile_r['datetime']}<br>{$profile_r['src']}"
        );        
    }


    $other_data=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT fname,datetime FROM other_tbl")
    while($other=mysqli_fetch_array($other_data))
    {

        $array[] = array(
            'title' => 'other',
            'value' => $other['fname'],
            'datetime' => $other['datetime'],
            'output' => "<br>{$other['datetime']}<br>{$other['fname']}"
        );  
    }

    $array = array_sort($array, 'datetime', SORT_DESC);

    $titles = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $data){
        if(! in_array($data['title'],$titles)){
            $titles[] = $data['title'];
            echo "load: {$data['title'}<br>";
        }

        echo $data['output'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it in one loop, then combine the data using SQL into the order you want it...

```
<?php  
   $status_res=mysqli_query($cn,
           "SELECT datetime,status FROM status
            UNION
            SELECT datetime,src FROM profile_photo
            UNION 
            SELECT datetime, fname FROM other_tbl
            ORDER BY 1
");    
   while($status=mysqli_fetch_array($status_res))
   {
     echo "load status";
      echo "<br>".$status['datetime'];
      echo "</br>". $status['status'];
   }
?>
```

Problem with this is that you don't know what type of record each one is.  You could add a new column and something like

```
SELECT 'a' as type, datetime,status FROM status
            UNION
            SELECT 'b', datetime,src FROM profile_photo
            UNION
            SELECT 'c', datetime, fname FROM other_tbl
            ORDER BY 2
```

would now give you a column called type, so `$status['type']` will tell you what the type of data is.